# contradictory results from box test & ACF/PACF plots of Seasonal ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, timeserieschart

I have used ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,1)12 where seasonal lag is 12. The ACF plot & PACF plot of residuals suggests pattern where as box test for 12 lags, 24 lags etc shows p value in the range of 20% to 40% indicating randomness.

Is it really possible to have contradictory results OR there might be a problem in the way i modeled it.

I am using Arima function of R.

The original series has strong seasonality and upward trend.

Regards

Lakshmi

Comment: I would expect similar conclusions based on the ACF and Box test. If you can post your data (the output from `dput(your.data)`) we could have a more detailed insight into it and would be easier to help you.